# How can i get the output of this map in my data collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to the image url from this collection.....
but i keep getting error like

```
Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: call()
```

here is my code

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Card(
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                child: Image.network(
                  snapshot.data.docs[index]
                      .data()['favourite'][0]
                      .profilePictureUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.....
Thanks

Comment: In your Database, the name of the collection is ```User_Favourites``` but you have used ```favourite``` ?

Comment: I just want to get the data from favourite map.... I am using it with streambuilder....

Comment: instead of ```.profilePictureUrl``` use ```['profilePictureUrl']```

Comment: I have use that is not working...

Comment: show your code that calls `querySnapshot.call()` method. error says there is no method called `call`.

Comment: Okay....I will show you....

Comment: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('favourite')
            .doc(_auth.currentUser.uid)
            .collection('User_Favorite')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          print(
              '.................${snapshot.data()['favourite']['profilePictureUrl']}');
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

Comment: what is the output of snapshot.data.docs[index].data() ?

Comment: i have solved it... thanks so mush